# Delete duplicates from two lists (bash)

Tags: bash, awk

I have two lists containing absolute paths of all files in PWD.

I generated this list from using `find "$(pwd)" -type f`

List 1:

```
/home/ec2-user/eclipsebio_toolkit/scripts/get_gene_counts_for_miRNA_specific_chimeric.py
/home/ec2-user/eclipsebio_toolkit/scripts/get_gene_info_sample_comparisons.py
/home/ec2-user/eclipsebio_toolkit/scripts/get_miRNA_counts_for_gene_specific_chimeric.py
/home/ec2-user/eclipsebio_toolkit/scripts/get_mrna_lengths.py
/home/ec2-user/eclipsebio_toolkit/scripts/get_nonnegative_peaks.py
/home/ec2-user/eclipsebio_toolkit/scripts/get_peak_gene_ids_chimeric.py
/home/ec2-user/eclipsebio_toolkit/scripts/get_peak_gene_ids_w_output.py
/home/ec2-user/eclipsebio_toolkit/scripts/get_peaks_not_sig.py
/home/ec2-user/eclipsebio_toolkit/scripts/get_peaks_overlapping_chimeric_reads.py
/home/ec2-user/eclipsebio_toolkit/scripts/create_ribo_html_report.py
```

List 2:

```
/home/ec2-user/snakemake_eclip/scripts/count_reads_broadfeatures_frombamfi_SRmap.pl
/home/ec2-user/snakemake_eclip/scripts/create_html_report.py
/home/ec2-user/snakemake_eclip/scripts/create_idr_html_report.py
/home/ec2-user/snakemake_eclip/scripts/create_mapped_read_num.py
/home/ec2-user/snakemake_eclip/scripts/create_metagene_plot_from_saturations.py
/home/ec2-user/snakemake_eclip/scripts/create_metagene_plot_from_saturations_peaks.py
/home/ec2-user/snakemake_eclip/scripts/create_metagene_plot_from_saturations_reads.py
/home/ec2-user/snakemake_eclip/scripts/create_peak_norm_manifests.py
/home/ec2-user/snakemake_eclip/scripts/create_pureclip_html_report.py
/home/ec2-user/snakemake_eclip/scripts/create_ribo_html_report.py
```

I would like to find duplicate files between these two lists and then delete duplicate items **only** found in list 1 (`rm` from disk).

I have tried using `awk 'NR == FNR{ a[$0] = 1;next } !a[$0]' list1 list2` to delete items only found in list 1, but this does not take the absolute path into consideration.

Comment: Yes, if a file is present in both list 1 and list 2, then I'd consider this a duplicate.

Comment: Is there always just 1 directory in each file? If not then please [edit] your example to show at least 2 directories per file and at least 2 cases where the same file name appears in multiple directories in 1 file, and add the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F'/' 'NR==FNR{ a[$NF]; next } $NF in a' file2 file1 | xargs rm
```

Always use the above `key in a` idiom for the second part of the script instead of `a[key]` as you were trying to do:

```
awk 'NR == FNR{ a[$0] = 1;next } !a[$0]' list1 list2
```

because what you're doing is wasting cycles and memory by storing `1` for every key that exists in your first file (`a[$0] = 1`) and then wasting more memory by storing every key from the 2nd file too with `!a[key]`.

This doesn't require you to assign any value when populating `a[key]` and tests if `key` exists in `a` by a hash lookup without adding anything else to `a[]`:

```
key in a
!(key in a)
```

while this does require you to initially assign a non-zero value to `a[key]` and then the code below does a hash lookup of `key` in `a[]` and if that key doesn't exist adds an entry to `a[]` indexed by `key` and then tests if the value for that entry is non-zero:

```
a[key]
!a[key]
```

so just don't do that as it's a waste of time and memory.

Comment: Okay ... are you using `$NF in a` as a condition itself for the final rule being either `0` or `1` to toggle the default `print` on/off? Never thought about that before -- brilliant. Or is something else escaping my eyes?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes, it's just testing if the condition "$NF exists as an index of a" is true or false, and if it's true then that invokes the default `print` action. I'm sure you must've seen that idiom many times before and just aren't remembering right now as `NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $0 in a` is the answer to the most frequently asked question asked here of how to find lines common (or not common if negated) between 2 files.

Answer (score 1):

Your awk script is almost right,

```
awk -F / 'NR == FNR{ a[$NF] = 1;next } a[$NF]' file2 file1
```

Comment: That'd use far more memory that necessary by adding an entry to `a` for every line inf `file1`.